# mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource error

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-num-rows

Can someone help me to solve this error:

mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource

This is my code:

```
$query = mysql_query($query);
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($numrows > 0){
```

Comment: Try:
$query = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
And post result of error. This is issue with query which might be invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this:-

```
$numrows = $query->num_rows;
```

Comment: This would supress warning, but would not work as expected. It won't return number of rows correctly - in fact it will return nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Rename your variable names:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($numrows > 0){
```

Comment: This is not issue here!
$query = mysql_query($query);
Above code is 100% correct

Comment: The php documentation says you must have a result as parameter.  He was passing the same variable name for the query and parameter (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php)

Comment: In case you don't know...
$query variable is changed in that line from string to result type.
PHP works that way - thx to that you can do for example $i=1;$i=$i+1; and result will be 2...

Comment: Yes, you're right ;-) but it's better do the correct way: one variable for each thing, or it'll lead to confusion later

Comment: It is good practice to assign different variables, but correct code is correct... so renaming variables here won't change a thing. It's query issue. I bet it is just SQL error.

Comment: But the error is "mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource", so it seems it is setting a non-resource variable (???).

Comment: @VancleiP - that's the error you get when your query fails. In that case, `mysql_query` returns a boolean false.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this one:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) {
   die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
else {
   $numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
      if ($numrows > 0){
      // put your code here
      }
   }
```